# Sharepoint 2010 cannot get to search results page

Tags: windows, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am running SharePoint 2010 on a single server set-up. (enterprise I believe).

I thought I had search set-up properly, but I cannot get to the search results page. It just throws an internal error, and I am not sure why.

I am getting the following from the correlation id in the log:

> CoreResultsWebPart::OnInit: Exception initializing:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e)
>
> Internal server error exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e)
>
> Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14,
>   06175311 "sharepoint server search", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", 17853a8f
>   "microsoft.office.server.search", 0e0017da "14.0.6106.0", 4def6b97
>   "wed jun 08 08:31:19 2011", 00003297 "00003297", 0000002d "0000002d",
>   4a6d3421 "nullreferenceexception", 67316a39 "g1j9"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am available for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the account that was used to create the search application (one specifically created for search) did not have enough permissions to actually access the search database.

I re-created the search application service, with an account of higher privileges, and that worked.